# tokens generation in smart-contracts specific to one asset

Tags: solidity, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, tokens, erc-20

I have been building a smart-contract for tokens for songs such that they are specific to different songs such that one token is only valid for one specific song not other. Ive made a smart-contract which does exactly that but does not follow ERC-20 and so the tokens do not show in the mist wallet. What is the best approach, to inherit ERC-20 in my smart contract and make it have the total supply of all tokens for all songs?? If yes then I would need the initial supply to be increased dynamically, is that possible(or should even be done)?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there. I think this question will get flagged as either too broad, or opinion-based, I'm afraid. This sort of question often leads to discussion, with no single answer being considered "correct". Reddit might be a better place for such design-related questions: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum

Comment: @shubhabrata-mukherjee take a look at the ERC-721 standard for non-fungible tokens

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create tokens that are specific to different songs they are not going to be [fungible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility) and may require implementation in separate contracts. It's good practice to have fungible tokens as they may be easily traded and transferred. For a more theoretical introduction to tokens properties you ma read this [tokens taxonomy](https://medium.com/@heckerhut/a-blockchain-token-taxonomy-fadf5c56139a).

The best approach is to extend your token from a popular and audited ERC-20 reference implementation like [StandardToken](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol).

Yes, you may increase the initial supply of tokens by a process which is often named `minting`. It's a good practice to inform all of the token holders about the rules for new token creation as the process may create an inflation and depreciate the value of held tokens.